# How to use merge on linked servers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, merge

Is it possible to use the merge statement on linked servers? If so how?

I have tried the following but it generates an error message

> The target of a MERGE statement cannot be a remote table, a remote
>   view, or a view over remote tables.

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server=N'devServer',
@srvproduct=N'',
@provider=N'SQLNCLI',
@datasrc=N'192.168.2.58\SQLSERVER';

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver
@server=N'localServer',
@srvproduct=N'',
@provider=N'SQLNCLI',
@datasrc=N'localhost\SQLSERVER';

Merge devServer.<dbName>.dbo.<tableName> as Target
USING localServer.<dbName>.dbo.<tableName> as Source
On (Source.HubID = Target.HubID)
When Matched then
    update set
        NAME = Source.NAME,
        CODE = Source.CODE,
        IPAddress = Source.IPAddress
When Not Matched Then
    Insert(, , ,)
    Values (, , ,);

    select * from sys.Servers
```

Comment: You can run your statement on 'devServer' and only use linked server as your source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported in Microsoft SQL Server 2008. From the [msdn documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx),

> *target_table* cannot be a remote table.

You can read more about it [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Comment: @Abi are you just trying to sync the servers? One way or two way? Do you have to use merge?