# How to merge two databases on two different servers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, connection-string, sql-server-express

I have two different databases, the client one is attached from a `.MDF` file to a `.\SQLEXPRESS` server. The master one is running on a server on another computer called `COMPUTER_NAME`.

I want to merge these using C# to run a `.SQL` file. I'll paste my code below for reference, but basically my problem is that if I connect to the server using

```
 string sqlConnectionString = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Trusted_Connection=True";
```

Then I can't find the database on `COMPUTER_NAME`. And if I use

```
 string sqlConnectionString = @"Server=COMPUTER_NAME; Trusted_Connection=True";
```

It will look for my `.MDF` file on the C: drive of `COMPUTER_NAME`, not the local machine.

How can I connect to both of these databases on different servers?

**Additional info:**

The SQL script I'm using. This worked perfectly back when both the databases were on the same server, but I can't do that anymore.

```
CREATE DATABASE ClientDB  
ON (Filename = 'C:\Clayton.mdf')
   , (Filename = 'C:\Clayton_log.ldf') 
FOR ATTACH;

-- update the client from the master 
MERGE [ClientDB].[dbo].[table] trgt
using [MasterDB].[dbo].[table] src
ON trgt.id = src.id 

WHEN matched AND trgt.lastmodified <= src.lastmodified THEN -- if master row is newer 
   UPDATE SET trgt.[info] = src.[info], ...                 -- update the client 

WHEN NOT matched BY source                                  -- delete rows added by client 
   THEN DELETE 

WHEN NOT matched BY target                                  -- insert rows added by master 
   THEN INSERT ( [info], ... ) VALUES (src.[info], ... ); 


-- close all connections to database
ALTER DATABASE ClientDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE; 

-- detach database
EXEC sp_detach_db 'ClientDB', 'true';
```

And I run it using C# like so:

```
 string sqlConnectionString = @"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Trusted_Connection=True";

 string script = File.ReadAllText(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\MergeTotal.sql");
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);

 IEnumerable<string> commandStrings = Regex.Split(script, @"^\s*GO\s*$",
                            RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

 conn.Open();
 foreach (string commandString in commandStrings)
 {
     if (commandString.Trim() != "")
     {
         using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandString, conn))
         {
             command.ExecuteNonQuery();
         }
     }
 }
```

I don't care if the entire process happens in the `.SQL` or in `C#` so long as it has the desired effect.

Thanks in advance for any guidance or recommendations.

Comment: How often do you need to run this?

Comment: Often I'm afraid. Right now it's configured that every time the program starts, it checks to see if it's connected to the network with the master database and will merge if it is.

Comment: You might have to consider a redesign of how it works then, as you can't really merge like that. You should probably track changes and then reenact them on the master server.

Comment: That's not really a feasible option for my purposes. There must be some way to script both databases. I'm playing around with `sp_addlinkedserver` and I think I'm on the right track.

Comment: So after much ado about nothing it turns out [you can't use a merge on linked servers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413977/how-to-use-merge-on-linked-servers), so I'm back where I started...

Answer (score 2):

Linking the servers would help you to be able to access the data simultaneously, if that's the requirement.  If you're looking to merge data together, though, I'd suggest you check out [sp_generate_merge](https://github.com/readyroll/generate-sql-merge/blob/master/master.dbo.sp_generate_merge.sql) to pull the data into a merge script for you (very handy for moving data).  See also my question on generating merge data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29989065/population-of-visual-studio-database-project-data-loading-scripts-from-existing).

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you give me an example of how I would use that in this situation? I need to merge both ways to commit both version's changes, but I keep getting the error `the target of a MERGE statement cannot be a remote table`.

Comment: You'd need to generate the merge script on one machine, copy the output, and run that merge on the other machine.  Then you'd reverse the process.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I had to completely throw out the whole `.MDF` thing. Instead of attaching and reattaching the database from an `.MDF`, I just set up the database.

Here's my code to initialize the local database on the tablet:

```
CREATE DATABASE LocalClaytonDB  
ON (Filename = 'C:\ProgramData\Clayton\Clayton.mdf')
   , (Filename = 'C:\ProgramData\Clayton\Clayton_log.ldf') 
FOR ATTACH;
GO

EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='Server'
```

Here's my code to synchronize the two databases:

```
-- update the client from the master 
MERGE [LocalClaytonDB].[dbo].[tableName] trgt
using [Server].[Clayton].[dbo].[tableName] src

ON trgt.id = src.id 

WHEN matched AND trgt.lastmodified <= src.lastmodified THEN 
  -- if the master has a row newer than the client
  -- update the client                       
  UPDATE SET trgt.[allColumns]      = src.[allColumns],
             trgt.[id]              = src.[id], 
             trgt.[lastmodified]    = src.[lastmodified] 

-- delete any rows added by a client 
WHEN NOT matched BY source 
THEN 
  DELETE 

-- insert any rows added by the master 
WHEN NOT matched BY target 
THEN 
  INSERT ( [allColumns], 
           [id], 
           [lastmodified]) 
  VALUES (src. [allColumns], 
          src.[id], 
          src.[lastmodified]); 


-- now we update the master from the client
-- Note:
-- because the serverDB is a linked server 
-- we can't use another MERGE statement, otherwise
-- we get the error: "The target of a MERGE statement 
-- cannot be a remote table, a remote view, or a view over remote tables."

UPDATE
    serverDB

SET 
    [allColumns]        = [localDB].[allColumns],
    [id]                = [localDB].[id], 
    [lastmodified]      = [localDB].[lastmodified] 

FROM 
     [Server].[Clayton].[dbo].[tableName] serverDB

INNER JOIN
     [LocalClaytonDB].[dbo].[tableName] localDB

-- update where the id is the same but the client is newer than the master

ON serverDB.id = localDB.id 
       AND localDB.lastmodified >= serverDB.lastmodified
```